# Traceback error: Does idlex need to be installed in a particular location?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide

I am running Python-2.7.8.AMD64 and installed idlex at the suggestion of a friend.

When I fire up idlex using a shortcut, a Dos box pops up with a Traceback as indicated in the attached codebox.

```
idlex.py - Shortcut

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\downloads\python\idlex-1.12\idlexlib\extensionManager.py", line 131,
in load_extension
    mod = importlib.import_module('.' + fullname, package=__package__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\downloads\python\idlex-1.12\idlexlib\extensions\IPyIDLE.py", line 253
, in <module>
    class IdleXSubSocketChannel(SimpleChannel, channels.IOPubChannel):
NameError: name 'channels' is not defined
could not load IPyIDLE
```

I am not sure what this means.

idlex runs as expected with no obvious errors that I can determine.

Does idlex need to be installed in a particular location in relation to Python to eliminate this error? (i.e. in the python folder in Lib?)

Thank you.

Comment: The error it's referring to is `NameError: name 'channels' is not defined` in the class definition shown in the line above. You can run idlex from anywhere, because Python should be in your PATH.

Comment: Thank you Signus, I guess my next question is why am I getting this error at all. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python and idlex several times thinking there may be some linking happening, but with the identical error each time.

Is this just an innocuous error that I can ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing IPython.

You may do either a `pip install ipython` or `easy_install ipython`, refer to [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) if you need help with that.

The error is a NameError saying that it does not have a definition for the variable `channels` which is called by the import that relies on IPython in "**idlex-1.12/idlex1.12/idlexlib/extension/IPyIDLE.py**":

```
if HAS_IPYTHON:
# IPython
...
import IPython.kernel.channels as channels
...
```

Where the error occurs is further down the file:

```
class IdleXSubSocketChannel(SimpleChannel, channels.IOPubChannel):
     channel_name = 'sub'
```

Once you've got IPython install that error is resolved, however you'll run into another error following that (if you have a base install):

```
ImportError: IPython.kernel.zmq requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

Which can be resolved by either `pip install pyzmq` or `easy_install pyzmq`, and once you've done that IdleX should run without throwing errors at you.

Comment: Ahh, I guess idlex was looking for iPython and pyzmq. Since I am a beginning Python user, I assume I do not need those two packages for now. Thank you for taking the time to explain everything to me.